# R Data Table add rows to each group if not existing

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with multiple groups. Each group I'd like to fill with rows containing the values in `vals` if they are not already present. Additional columns should be filled with NAs.

```
DT = data.table(group = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3), val = c(1,2,4,2,3,1,2,3,4), somethingElse = rep(1,9)) 
vals = data.table(val = c(1,2,3,4))
```

What I want:

```
    group val somethingElse
 1:     1   1             1
 2:     1   2             1
 3:     1   3            NA
 4:     1   4             1
 5:     2   1            NA
 6:     2   2             1
 7:     2   3             1
 8:     2   4            NA
 9:     3   1             1
10:     3   2             1
11:     3   3             1
12:     3   4             1
```

The order of `val` does not necessarily have to be increasing, the values may also be appened at the beginning/end of each group.

I don't know how to approach this problem. I've thought about using `rbindlist(...,fill = TRUE)`, but then the values will be simply appended.
I think some expression with `DT[, lapply(...), by = c("group")]` might be useful here but I have no idea how to check if a value already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cross-join:

```r
setDT(DT)[
  CJ(group = group, val = val, unique = TRUE), 
  on = .(group, val)
]

    group val somethingElse
 1:     1   1             1
 2:     1   2             1
 3:     1   3            NA
 4:     1   4             1
 5:     2   1            NA
 6:     2   2             1
 7:     2   3             1
 8:     2   4            NA
 9:     3   1             1
10:     3   2             1
11:     3   3             1
12:     3   4             1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your problem:

```
DT[, .SD[vals, on="val"], by=group]

    group   val somethingElse
 1:     1     1             1
 2:     1     2             1
 3:     1     3            NA
 4:     1     4             1
 5:     2     1            NA
 6:     2     2             1
 7:     2     3             1
 8:     2     4            NA
 9:     3     1             1
10:     3     2             1
11:     3     3             1
12:     3     4             1

# or
DT[CJ(group, val, unique=TRUE), on=.NATURAL]
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just add this answer for a slightly more complex case:

```
#Raw Data
DT = data.table(group = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  x = c(1,2,1,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                  y = c(2,4,2,6,8,2,4,6,8),
                  somethingElse = rep(1,9))

#allowed combinations of x and y
DTxy = data.table(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(2,4,6,8))
```

Here, I want to add all `x`,`y` combinations from `DTxy` to each group from `DT`, if not already present.

I've wrote a function to work for subsets.

```
#function to join subsets on two columns (here: x,y)
DTxyJoin = function(.SD, xy){
  .SD = .SD[xy, on = .(x,y)]
  return(.SD)
}
```

I then applied the function to each group:

```
#add x and y to each group if missing
DTres = DT[, DTxyJoin(.SD, DTxy), by = c("group")]
```

The Result:

```
    group x y somethingElse
 1:     1 1 2             1
 2:     1 2 4             1
 3:     1 3 6            NA
 4:     1 4 8            NA
 5:     2 1 2             1
 6:     2 2 4            NA
 7:     2 3 6             1
 8:     2 4 8             1
 9:     3 1 2             1
10:     3 2 4             1
11:     3 3 6             1
12:     3 4 8             1
```